# Having an issue with YACC grammar

Tags: compilation, grammar, bison, yacc

The code I wrote seems to not be able to detect a function. I tried many edits but nothing seems to be working.

```
program :  function-decl  | decl | function-def  
        ;

decl : kind var-list SEMICOLON 
        { 
        tok_type = "variable";
        }
        ;

kind : KW_INT {integer = true; floatType = false;} 
     | KW_FLOAT {integer = false; floatType = true;}
     ;

var-list : ID varmany
         {
         tok_type = "variable";
         t.check_token (tok_type, $1, line_no, bodyCheck, parameter);
         }
         ;

varmany : /*empty*/ | varmany COMMA ID 
        {
         tok_type = "variable";
         t.check_token (tok_type, $3,  line_no, bodyCheck, parameter );
        }
        ;


function-decl : kind ID LPAR kind RPAR SEMICOLON             
              {

              current_func = $2;
              declaration = true; 
              parameter= false; 
              tok_type= "function";

              t.check_token (tok_type, current_func,  line_no, bodyCheck, parameter );
              current_func ="";
              }
              ; 

function-def : kind ID LPAR kind ID RPAR body 
             {
             current_func = $2; 
             paramName = $5;
             declaration = false; 
             parameter= false; 
             tok_type= "function";
             t.check_token (tok_type, current_func, line_no, bodyCheck, parameter );

             tok_type = "variable"; 
             parameter=true;
             t.check_token(tok_type, paramName,  line_no, bodyCheck, parameter);
             current_func ="";
             }
             ;
```

For example, for text input :

```
int main (int DUMMY) {    
    int x,y,z; 
    float p;    
    int main (int x){x = y;}    
    p = -z * (x/345+y*1.0) + - 300;    
    p = -z * (x/345+y*1.0) + -300; 

   while (p>=-(x+y)*3.45/6-z)
     z = z + 3;
}
```

I get these error messages:

> Local int variable y declared in line 3.
>   Local int variable z declared in line 3.
>   Local int variable x declared in line 3.
>   Local float variable p declared in line 5.
>   Local int variable main declared in line 6.
>   syntax error on line 6, matched: (
>   Local int variable x declared in line 6.
>   syntax error on line 6, matched: )

Comment: The Bison I've got (v2.3 on a Mac) won't accept the dashes in the rule names like `function-decl`; they have to be replaced with underscores.  Which version are you using?  Is this really your code?  It isn't an MCVE ([MCVE]) because you've not defined the rule for `body`, and because none of the support functions are provided.  Can you fix those problems?  It doesn't have to provide support for expressions — indeed, the MCVE shouldn't do that.

Comment: Is the problem related to the long common prefix between `function-decl` and `function-def`?  Have you compiled with debug enabled (`-DYYDEBUG`, or similar — double check)?  Have you looked hard at the output from `-v` (`y.output` or a similar file name)?  Have you checked that the correct tokens are being returned by the lexical analyzer?  Is the sample code the minimal code that illustrates the problem?

Comment: @Johnathan: That's quite an old bison version (2005, I believe). Perhaps you should consider installing a more modern version. I think dashes in symbols were added around 2009. The current bison manual says "Symbol names can contain letters, underscores, periods, and non-initial digits and **dashes**.  Dashes in symbol names are a GNU extension, incompatible with POSIX Yacc.  Periods and dashes make symbol names less convenient to use with named references, which require brackets around such names..."

Answer (score 0):

Your `function_decl` rule insists on exactly one parameter and does not allow for its name.